# Issue when writing a list to binary file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix X of size (`n*n`) that I want to write into two separate binary files (i.e., n/2 of rows that satisfies a condition must go to a file and the remaining to another). I wrote it as the following code:

```
def write_to_binary_file(X, y):
    posiResponse = []
    negaResponse = []
    for idx, res in enumerate(y):
        if res == 1:
            posiResponse.extend(X[idx])
        else:
            negaResponse.extend(X[idx])

    with open("POS.bin", mode='wb') as file1:
        file1.write(bytearray(posiResponse))
    file1.close()
    with open("NEG.bin", mode='wb') as file2:
        file2.write(bytearray(negaResponse))
    file2.close()
```

I get an error that complains about the arrays and how I use `bytearray()` but I don't know how to tweak it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exper.py", line 173, in <module>
    write_data(X, y)
  File "exper.py.py", line 47, in write_data
    file1.write(bytearray(posiResponse))
TypeError: an integer or string of size 1 is required
```

Kindly, can someone provide a good fix? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to write a numpy array to a binary file? Do you care how it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posiResponse` and `negaResponse` are lists. Numpy has ways that enable you to easily write to files. Here's one way using [`np.ndarray.tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html):

```
def write_to_binary_file(X, y):
    ... # populate posiResponse and negaResponse here

    np.array(posiResponse).tofile('POS.bin')
    np.array(negaResponse).tofile('NEG.bin')
```

Alternatively, you may retain these data structures as lists and then use the [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) from the `pickle` module to dump your data:

```
import pickle
def write_to_binary_file(X, y):
    ... # populate posiResponse and negaResponse here

    pickle.dump(posiResponse, open('POS.bin', 'wb'))
    pickle.dump(negaResponse, open('NEG.bin', 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @COLDSPEED's answer you can use [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html):

```
def write_to_binary_file(X, y):
    posiResponse = []
    negaResponse = []
    for idx, res in enumerate(y):
        if res == 1:
            posiResponse.extend(X[idx])
        else:
            negaResponse.extend(X[idx])
    np.save('POS', posiResponse)
    np.save('NEG', negaResponse)
```

Unfortunately, it will add extension `npy`.

Later, you can load lists back as:

```
posiResponse = np.load('POS.npy').tolist()
```